# Database Organization - Website containing many articles

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to organize articles written on my website.  Currently, I have an author submit their work to me (via email) and I copy/paste their article into a .php file and upload their file with FTP.  At the same time I need to update the links for the navigation menu based on the new article.

I've been reading that I can put everything into a mysql database.

Right now, I have 2 Columns (a music column and a college life column) -  each column will have articles updated every two weeks by a different author.  How do I organize my database

What I was thinking...(after doing some reading)

**Table Column:**

```
Column_id
Name
Description
Create_date
```

**Table Column_authors:**

```
column_id
author_id
```

**Table Articles:**

```
Article_id
column_id
Title
Description/Summary
Body
create_date
```

**Table Articles_authors:**

```
article_id
author_id
```

**Table Articles_keyword:**

```
article_id
keyword_id
```

**Table authors:**

```
author_id
Name
Email
about
```

**Table Keyword**

```
keyword_id
name
```

?????
(I'm not sure how to organize with the keyword - each article can have multiple keywords)

I'm completely new to organizing with a database, so I have no idea what I'm doing!

Could someone, point me in the right direction of a good tutorial.

Please let me know if I need to be more specific

Comment: Looks like you're already sorted - the `Articles_keyword` table associates M articles with N keywords. What's the problem?

Comment: Great!  I felt totally lost, feels good to know that I understand it a little bit.  So, when I add a new article to the database, I need to update each table, correct? And, the ****_id should be a number and I just add it manually?  If I end up with a bunch of keywords (with a certain ID #) how would I remember which ID# corresponds to the keyword?   Also, (this is probably a very stupid question) once I upload the new article (ie text files) how is the article URL created?  like, www.mysite.com/columnname/article1.php this is probably a basic question, so a good tutorial would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/). WordPress is built on top of a MySQL database, but you don't really to to mess around with it too much other than setting it up initially, if that (some hosting sites have an automated WordPress install that sets up the database for you).

Once you are all set up, then you can use Posts in WordPress for your articles and the latest article is displayed first, with links to the old ones automatically generated. If you have any static content, you can use Pages in WordPress.

Comment: So, my questions becomes.  Which is more difficult/time consuming, integrating wordpress into my website design (basically, creating a wordpress theme) or creating a CMS myself?